# How to pass boost ranges to a function that accepts any_range

Tags: c++, boost, boost-range

I am trying to write a class function which accepts `boost::any_range` which is a double-random access range. My purpose is to be able to pass any kind of that range to the function which can be an `std::vector`, `std::deque`, or a boost range. The code works for `std::vector` and `std::deque`, however it gives a warning when I try with a boost range.

I tried this:

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using Range = boost::any_range<const double, boost::random_access_traversal_tag, const double>;

struct Indexer {
    Indexer(const double param_) : param(param_) {}

    double operator()(const int i) const
    {
        return static_cast<double>(i) + param;
    }

private:
    const double param;
};

class Temp {
public:
    void workWithAnyRange(const Range& range) {
        workWithAnyRangeTemplated(range);
    }

private:
    template<typename R>
    void workWithAnyRangeTemplated(const R& r) {
        for (auto i : r) {
            std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Temp temp;

    temp.workWithAnyRange(std::vector<double>{1,2,3});
    temp.workWithAnyRange(std::deque<double>{1,2,3});
    temp.workWithAnyRange(boost::irange(0, 10) | boost::adaptors::transformed(Indexer(15.0))); //introduces the warning

    return 0;
}
```

And the following output I got:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/any_range.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:5:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp: In member function 'boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::dereference() const [with WrappedIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::range_detail::default_constructible_unary_fn_wrapper<Indexer, double>, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<int>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; Reference = double; Difference = long int; Buffer = boost::any_iterator_buffer<64ul>; boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference = double&]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp:510:57: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
                 return dereference_cast<reference>(*m_it);
                                                         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp:510:51: note: declared here
                 return dereference_cast<reference>(*m_it);
                                                   ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/any_range.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:5:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp: In member function 'boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::dereference() const [with WrappedIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::range_detail::default_constructible_unary_fn_wrapper<Indexer, double>, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<int>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; Reference = double; Difference = long int; Buffer = boost::any_iterator_buffer<64ul>; boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference = double&]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp:510:57: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
                 return dereference_cast<reference>(*m_it);
                                                         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp:510:51: note: declared here
                 return dereference_cast<reference>(*m_it);
                                                   ^
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 15
i: 16
i: 17
i: 18
i: 19
i: 20
i: 21
i: 22
i: 23
i: 24
```

As you see, it outputs something but the warning seems concerning. If I remove the line where I called the function with `boost::irange`, the warning disappears. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: What compiler and setting are you seeing that warning on? No warning [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6vY51WTzj)

Comment: I am using gcc 5.4 with -std=c++ as it is seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wc13dxsc6)

Comment: I got the feeling that I messed up with the compiler options, because [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5oc673Ers) seems like it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got the feeling that I messed up with the compiler options, because this seems like it works –
> user1508716
> 4 mins ago

Nah, that's just because that includes the boost include directory with `-isystem` instead of `-I` hiding the warnings.

The warning indicates that the result of the transform - an rvalue - is returned by reference. Rather  surprising since you requested the reference type to be `double const`. Indeed, the error message confirms:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_71_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp: In member function '
boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::dereference()
const [with 
WrappedIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::range_detail::default_constructible_unary_fn_wrapper<Indexer, double>, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<int>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>;
Reference = double;
Difference = long int;
Buffer = boost::any_iterator_buffer<64ul>;
boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference = double&;
]':
```

Note how it comfirms that `Reference = double` as you requested (top-level const is not significant in function signatures in C++). However, it deems `boost::range_detail::any_random_access_iterator_wrapper<WrappedIterator, Reference, Difference, Buffer>::reference = double&`, making the implementation of `dereference` unsafe:

```
virtual reference dereference() const
{
    return dereference_cast<reference>(*m_it);
}
```

Comparing with Boost 1.81.0 shows no problem: https://godbolt.org/z/9qfTzn15T

Indeed boost 1.74.0 contains a fix: https://godbolt.org/z/vEe118f6G

Indeed boost 1.73.0 still had the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/EM56Pss5q

The change involved appears to be

```
474efda Merge pull request #94 from mjendruk/fix-any-range-non-reference-references
```

Which links to https://github.com/boostorg/range/pull/94 "Fix any_range with non-reference references can cause UB"

Comment: Is there any workaround to overcome this issue since I cant change the boost version unfortunately? Basically I need a function which can expect a double range which should support random access

Comment: This needs better framing. I'd say you cannot afford _not to upgrade_ tools for a decade. You can trivially do it by not type-erasing the range (`workWithAnyRangeTemplated`). Or you can not use temporaries - that require buffering anyways, so they won't be performant at all: https://godbolt.org/z/zEx87vPPK